# Help creating equation for parabola word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> The cable of a suspension bridge hangs in the shape of a parabola. The towers supporting the cable are $400$ ft apart and $150$ ft high. If the cable, at its lowest is $30$ ft above the bridge at its midpoint, how high is the cable $50$ ft away (horizontally) from either tower?

I tried the formula $y^2=4cx$ and $x^2=4cx$ but I still don't know the answer. I'm confused.

Comment: It is not sufficient to post the exercise only. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try drawing the curve such that the lowest point is at the origin.  What portion spans $400$ feet?  What portion spans $150$ feet?  Translate these into $(x, y)$ coordinates.  Find the expression of the form $y = kx^2$ that passes through all located points.  Then where is the actual bridge (where people cross)?  It should be of the form $y = h$.  What portion spans $30$ feet?  Translate that into the value of $h$.  That should get you there; if you still need help, you should edit your attempt with this framework into the question.

Comment: Where did you take the origin? Can you add a diagram to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Find $a$ in the parabola form:

$$ k= 30, \;y(x)-k = a  x^2 \,@ (x= 200,y=150) $$

Next find $$ y(x) @ x=\pm(200-50) $$